# How to determine if the number has identical digits in C

Tags: c

Efficient way to determine if the number has identical digits in C

Comment: What do you mean by identical digits? something like: 9999?

Comment: Be more specific; give examples. Do you want a boolean yes/no for if there are any repeated digits at all? Should the function return the total number of repeat digits? Etc.

Comment: sheesh, let the guy rephrase the question so its better before closing it, or rephrase it yourself

Answer (score 4):

if its just for repeating occurances in decimal within the same number :-

```
int contains_repeat(int x)
{
    int occurances = 0;
    while(x>0)
    {
          if(occurances & 1 << (x % 10)) return 1;
          occurances |= 1 << (x % 10);
          x = x / 10;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

if its all the same

```
int all_the_same(int x)
{
    int digit = x%10;
    while(x>0)
    {
        if(x%10 != digit) return 0;
        x = x/10;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

if you want it for a different base, just pass "int base" in and use base instead of 10.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
if (4444 % 1111 == 0) // all digits are the same
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you would want to convert it to string first (so you can easily work with digits of a number). And then apply whatever usual string algorithms you want.